# I'm having a problem with my test, when I run them I'm getting error

Tags: javascript, testing, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm having a problem with my test, when I run them I'm getting this error:

> Contract: Electionn
>       √ initializes with two candidates
>       1) it initializes the candidates with the correct values
>
> > No events were emitted
>
> 1 passing (89ms)   1 failing
>
> 1) Contract: Electionn
>          it initializes the candidates with the correct values:
>        ReferenceError: Election is not defined
>         at Context. (test\election.js:16:5)
>         at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\testrunner.js:135:1
>         at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\property.js:119:1
>         at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:89:1
>         at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
>         at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
>         at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
>         at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

and my test file is :

```
var Electionn = artifacts.require("./Electionn.sol");

contract("Electionn", function(accounts) {
  var electionInstance;

  it("initializes with two candidates", function() {
    return Electionn.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.candidatesCount();
    }).then(function(count) {
      assert.equal(count, 2);
    });
  });

  it("it initializes the candidates with the correct values", function() {
    return Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      electionInstance = instance;
      return electionInstance.candidates(1);
    }).then(function(candidate) {
      assert.equal(candidate[0], 1, "contains the correct id");
      assert.equal(candidate[1], "Candidate 1", "contains the correct name");
      assert.equal(candidate[2], 0, "contains the correct votes count");
      return electionInstance.candidates(2);
    }).then(function(candidate) {
      assert.equal(candidate[0], 2, "contains the correct id");
      assert.equal(candidate[1], "Candidate 2", "contains the correct name");
      assert.equal(candidate[2], 0, "contains the correct votes count");
    });
 });
});
```

I don't know how to solve it, thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did the Election variable come from? you called it Electionn as far as I see

Comment: the Electionn (its just a name )not Election :this is the name of my contract and in migrate.js file we initialize the electionn var

Comment: but you have one line in the first test saying "   return Electionn.deployed().then(function(instance) {" which I think is the correct one and then you have in the second test "return Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {" ... notice the Election vs Electionn

Comment: Maybe typo error? See this https://i.imgur.com/nn2ZRB9.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference the deployed version of the contract for testing purposes...

Try initializing your contract instance before each test, and use a global variable to reference it.

```js
var electionnInstance;

beforeEach(function() {
    return Electionn.new()
    .then(function(instance) {
        electionnInstance = instance;
    });
});

it("..."
```

Comment: Also as a suggestion, you might benefit from using `await` to make the tests more readable:

const count = await instance.candidatesCount();